# Relation between determinant of the cofactor matrix and the matrix itself?

Tags: matrices

If the cofactor matrix of A is
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I find the determinant of $A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Let $C$ be the cofactor matrix, then $$C^TA = \det(A)I$$  Take the determinant of both sides of this to get $$\det(C^TA) = \det(\det(A)I) \\ \det(C^T)\det(A) = \det(A)^3\det(I) = \det(A)^3$$

Comment: so the determinant of C transpose is equal to det(A)^2?

Comment: As long as $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix -- yep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $BA=||A||I$ where $B$ is the adjoint of $A$.

Comment: IMO, it's better to call it the *adjugate* of $A$ and reserve the word adjoint for the (conjugate) transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two solutions:

$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 \\ -7 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_2=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 7 & -2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

You can find these by computing $B={C^{T}}^{-1}$ and solving $A=kB$ and $k=\det(A)$.

$\det(A_1)=-2$ and $\det(A_2)=2$.